# How to add Gaussian noise or any other noise to a sine wave (using VHDL)?

Tags: vhdl

We need a noisy sine wave signal. We have generated the sine wave (using VHDL), but we can't figure out how to add noise to it. We are including the code for sine wave generation. Kindly mention how to add Gaussian or any other noise to it.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  --try to use this library as much as possible.

entity sine_wave is
port (clk :in  std_logic;
      data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
      );
end sine_wave;

architecture Behavioral of sine_wave is
signal i : integer range 0 to 29:=0;
--type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of integer;
type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=("01001101","01011101","01101100","01111010","10000111","10010000","10010111","10011010","10011010","10010111","10010000","10000111","01111010","01101100","01011101","01001101",
"00111101","00101110","00100000","00010011","00001010","00000011","00000000","00000000","00000011","00001010","00010011","00100000","00101110","00111101");
--hi
begin

process(clk)
begin
  --to check the rising edge of the clock signal
if(rising_edge(clk)) then     
data_out <= sine(i);
i <= i+ 1;
if(i = 29) then
i <= 0;
end if;
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the purpose of the noise there are different possibilities. I have already used one that consists in adding a percentage of randomness to your generated waveform.

First you need to add the library `IEEE.MATH_REAL.ALL`.
Then use the Uniform procedure:

```
procedure UNIFORM (variable Seed1,Seed2:inout integer; variable X:out real);
    -- returns a pseudo-random number with uniform distribution in the 
    -- interval (0.0, 1.0).
    -- Before the first call to UNIFORM, the seed values (Seed1, Seed2) must
    -- be initialized to values in the range [1, 2147483562] and 
    -- [1, 2147483398] respectively.  The seed values are modified after 
    -- each call to UNIFORM.
    -- This random number generator is portable for 32-bit computers, and
    -- it has period ~2.30584*(10**18) for each set of seed values.
```

For example you can create your behavioral process like this :

```
---------------------------------------
-- generates rdm numbers to simulate 
-- noise on the line
---------------------------------------
rdm : PROCESS
    VARIABLE seed1, seed2: positive;            
    VARIABLE rand: real;  
    VARIABLE rdm_rng : real := 419430.0; 
    VARIABLE rand_num_i : integer := 0;
BEGIN
    uniform(seed1, seed2, rand);
    rand_num_i  := integer(rand*rdm_rng) - 104858; -- rescaling
    rand_num <= to_signed(rand_num_i, 24);
    WAIT FOR tempo;
END PROCESS;
```

Finally you just need to add `rand_num` to your signal.

Comment: this is not gaussian, I am afraid

Comment: "Kindly mention how to add Gaussian/any other noise to it". Regards

Comment: Yeah I know, I would have asked for some clarification, or add something to you answer that explains how to turn a uniform random number in a gaussian random number, given mean and variance.

Comment: @A.Kieffer Sir, Sir what is this line of code doing: uniform(seed1,seed2,rand);.And sir how to declare uniform?

Comment: @A.Kieffer: Sir, why are you using WAIT FOR tempo; and How to declare tempo?

Comment: Uniform is a procedure included in the library Math_real. It returns a pseudo random number (real) between 0.0 and 1.0. Tempo is a just a time constant used to update the random number periodically (@ `tempo`frequency). You can instantiate it like `CONSTANT tempo : time := 20 ns;`

Comment: @A.Kieffer : Sir, How to declare uniform...An error is being shown that "uniform is not declared" ...How to overcome it?

Comment: Do you have included the Math_real library like I Said? `USE IEEE.MATH_REAL.ALL`

Comment: Yes sir, problem has been solved. :)...Sir one thing...This code is probably not synthesizable as we are using real variables in it. If we use fixed point arithmetic, then the code will probably be synthesizable? Thank you sir for helping us in this regard :)

Comment: Sir we are adding: "signal rand_num: signed"; after "architecture Behavioral of Noise1 is" to declare rand_num, we are getting an error that "to_signed is not declared". Do we need to add additional libraries for this?

Comment: @A.Kieffer  we are adding: "signal rand_num: signed"; after "architecture Behavioral of Noise1 is" to declare rand_num, we are getting an error that "to_signed is not declared". Do we need to add additional libraries for this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple to implement something like this https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4400

A pseudo-random sequence has all the statistical properties and spectral qualities of real world Gaussian white noise - except it does have a auto correlation function that is a Kronecker delta for one single point in the sequence. (maximal length sequence)